# Position UIView above tab bar in any orientation programmatically

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, autoresize, autoresizingmask

I have a UIView which I would like to have aligned just above the UITabBar in both portrait and landscape orientation. I would like to do this programmatically.

This is all I have in my UIView subclass, `IPChatTextView`:

```
/* Initialization */
- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        // Set frame
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40);

        // Create background
        UIEdgeInsets insetsBackground = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 50, 19, 82);
        UIImage *imageBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ChatTextView_Background.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:insetsBackground];
        UIImageView *imageViewBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
        imageViewBackground.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        imageViewBackground.image = imageBackground;

        // Add subviews
        [self addSubview:imageViewBackground];
    }

    return self;
}
```

The image view `imageViewBackground` should fill the entire UIView and therefore I have set it's autoresizing mask to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`. This works fine.

When initializing the view, I set it's autoresizing mask.

```
self.chatTextView = [[IPChatTextView alloc] init];
self.chatTextView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 327, 320, 40);
self.chatTextView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
[self.view addSubview:self.chatTextView];
```

I have tried adding a UIView in Interface Builder and set it's autoresizing mask as in the image below and it works perfectly.

[image: Autoresizing in Interface Builder]

I thought that when I want to have the same autoresizing as the image above, I would do it programmatically as the code below but it doesn't give me the same result. Instead it is positioned about 2/3 from the top, which seems odd as I set the y-position of the `self.chatTextView` to 327 which is just above the tab bar.

```
self.chatTextView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

Does anyone know how I should set my autoresizing mask when I want the view to be positioned above the tab bar in both portrait and landscape orientation?

**EDIT:**

If I change the autoresizing mask to include `UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleBottomMargin` instead of `UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleTopMargin`, the view is aligned above the tab bar in portrait mode but is gone out of the screen in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up positioning it programmatically when a rotation was detected.